# Package WebClient.DownloadStringAsync into function return a string

Tags: c#, webclient

I had a method downloading a string, parsing it and then returning the parsed data as a string[]. I now want to change that method so it uses the DownloadStringAsync, but I don't know how to still have it as a function return that string array.

Since the fetched string is parsed in the DownloadStringAsyncCompleted method and not in the method it was called from :S

Comment: Can you explain a little more.. it sounds like you want to use the async operation but still block?

Comment: @QuintinRobinson You are right. It won't work the way I want it, have to rethink it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot seamlessly transform synchronous code into asynchronous one. In your example, you should return void and accept another parameter of type Action (callback) that you should call in DownloadStringAsyncCompleted to signal that data has come.

C# 5 will help a little bit with that, but still async is async.

Comment: This is probably how I should do, though I will put the whole method, including DownloadString into a backgroundWorker instead. But this is the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

try [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) it is not async.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient ();
string reply = client.DownloadString (address);
Console.WriteLine (reply);
```

If you want to use DownloadStringAsync method you need to wait until DownloadStringAsyncCompleted  event fired. again it going to be sync method. if you really want a result to continue then use sync method.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method to trigger the start of the download Async via `DownloadStringAsync()`. Then move the code that parses it and returns a `string[]` into the method that handles the `DownloadStringAsyncCompleted` event.